# SQL-I have only one attribute as unique..how should I specify primary key for multiple tables?

Tags: sql

I have large data in excel with about 3000 rows and 40 columns. I have converted excel to csv and dumped the data into 6 tables in sql using "load data local infile" 
The problem is out of 40 columns only one column(attribute) is unique and all the other columns are either null or not unique. For now I have used only one primary key to all the tables. But I don't think it will be efficient in the future...can anyone please suggest an alternative way of doing this.

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-think on why you made it 6 tables instead of 1. If there is only 1 logical candidate key and every column relates directly to that key, then it should all be in 1 table.

Do some google searching on `database normalization` to get a better understanding of database design.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I wanted to split the data as it consists of around 40 columns. I wanted to group the tables based on their similarities...Is there any other way to accomplish this or do I just those in a single table?

Comment: Like I said, i strongly suggest doing research on database normalization to determine how to handle your specific data set

Answer (score 0):

First of all, that seems like a lot of data to be dealing with. From the sounds of it as well, there's probably a lot of redundancies considering the number of fields and low number of unique attributes. I would suggest taking out anything you don't need first and trying to eliminate as many duplicate entries as possible. Just give it a good look and if you have something like an email field as well as one for Instant Messaging that could end up being the same information. In that case, you could just combine it just have the email field.

Once that's done, you should go back and edit anything you want as the PK in the database to read PRIMARY for each table. It'll save you a lot of space in the database for overhead.

Comment: 3000 rows is hardly a lot of data

Comment: Thanks, there are not many redundancies, but I can merge 2 or 3 columns into one. I guess still the problem persists and even if I merge the columns they have lots of null values....Is it better to put in a single table?

Comment: Yes, less tables is better.. and as suggested below, look into normalization. it'll go a long way.